# Animation not working properly when three.js mixer clampwhenfinished method set true

Tags: animation, three.js, 3dsmax

I am trying to disassemble the gun using three.js. To do this I used an object modeled and I animized in 3dsmax. I have output them in [Json 3D Loader](http://www.cgdev.net/blog/482.html) format using cgdev json exporter.

My problem;  I want to animate the charger, back and forward. I prepare an animation at `3ds max` to insert the magazine and I played it, but I could not use a negative timescale because I used looponce to play back this animation. So I made the back animation in `3ds max` as well, but when I use the `clampwhenfinished = true` code, the animation is not playing back exactly.

```
var step;

next ? step = animAssemble[iTween] : step = animDissamble[iTween];

var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(camera.position).to(step.camera, step.tCam);
tween.onUpdate(function () { camera.position = step.camera });
tween.start();

tween.onComplete(function () {
    var mesh = meshes[step.gun], mixer = mixers[step.gun];
    animation = mixer.clipAction(mesh.geometry.animations[step.i]);
    animation.setLoop(THREE.LoopOnce);
    animation.clampWhenFinished = true;
    animation.play();
    anim = true;
});
```

Thanks.